# jQuery Hide function not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, html, firefox

I'm trying to perform a simple hide function with jQuery, which works fine in IE10, but does not work in Firefox (25.0.1). The set-up is basically as follows: I have a base HTML page with a content block and a button. Clicking the button should load html from another (local) page into the content block, but certain parts (in this case the divs with a class of "description") should be hidden. Here's the code:

**Base HTML page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test for jQuery Hide function in Firefox</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="hide.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="contentblock">This is where the content goes</div>
    <div id="button">Button</div>


</body>
   </html>
```

**HTML to be loaded:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test 2</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="step">
<div class="stepcontent">This is the second file, first div</div>
<div class="description">Description #1</div>
</div>

<div class="step">
<div class="stepcontent">This is the second file, second div</div>
<div class="description">Description #2</div>
</div>

<div class="step">
<div class="stepcontent">This is the second file, second div</div>
<div class="description">Description #3</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#button').click(function(){
        $('#contentblock').load( 'loadfile.html' );
        $('.description').hide();

    });
});
```

Again, the above code works fine in IE10, but not in Firefox. I have no way right now to check it in Chrome, since Chrome doesn't allow loading of locally stored HTML into another HTML page.
Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: Try to put ` $('.description').hide();` before the `.load()` function. So you can exclude if it is a `.load()` problem. EDIT: Sorry, my mistake. I just read the 'HTML to be loaded' title. Excuse me.

Comment: You should probably not load a complete html document into the `<div>`. This can probably have bad consequences in some browsers. Keep only the stuff inside the ´<body>´ of that second html file.

Comment: @GuyT, the `.description` content doesn't even exist in that point in time, as they are inside the content loaded from second document.

Comment: @peterherdenborg what if the other file have some javascript code written in it, may be a different external js.

Comment: I guess you have to be sure that the 'loadfile.html' is correctly loaded so you've to put the `.hide()` into a callback(http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: like guyT mentions, try this: ('#contentblock').load( 'loadfile.html', function(){  $('.description').hide()} );

Comment: @GuyT, you're absolutely right. The trick was to call the function in the load function itself (apparently it doesn't get initialized otherwise). I saw the answer in one of the comments which got deleted by the poster before I could mark it as correct. Will post a complete answer as soon as I can. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Always remember that you need to use callbacks in this kind of situations. It's not certain that the page to be loaded will ever load(eg. 404). Use callbacks if your function or variable depends on a previous call/action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help. The answer below was given by someone who then deleted the post before I could mark it as correct (so, whoever that was, thank you very much!). Just a few comments on some of the answers:

1. the config did not appear to be the problem, since the file was loading fine, just not hiding the classes I indicated.
2. @Peter I'll limit it to the body of the HTML. Thanks for the tip.

The answer was to include the hide function as a proper function in the load function, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#button').click(function(){
        $('#contentblock').load( 'loadfile.html', function(){  $('.description').hide();  } );
    });
});
```

Again, thanks everybody for the fast responses!

Answer (score 0):

To allow firefox to load local files (which may be where your script is halting), access the firefox config by typing "about:config" into the address bar.

Search for "origin"  and set "security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy" to false.

Comment: so one have to say each user to change the browser config that way.

Comment: i assume he's running it locally for development only and eventually it would be running on a webserver, in which case the browser security restrictions won't be an issue for loading content via js.